# How to validate url parameters bundle in parameter object in Spring's @RestController

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a standard `@RestController` method. I introduced a parameter-object (`MyMapQuery`) in order to avoid large number of method arguments:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {
  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/search")
  @ResponseBody
  public SearchResponse search(MyMapQuery query) {
    [...]
  }
```

`MyMapQuery` is a standard java bean with setters and getters, so when I pass multiple url parameters `http://.../api/search?west=1&east=2&north=20&south=0`, they are correctly filled in.

How do I implement required validation on some of the url parameters?

Spring automatically responds with 400(bad request), when parameters are mapped like below, but does no validation in case of `MyMapQuery`.

```
public SearchResponse search(@RequestParam BigDecimal east, @RequestParam BigDecimal west, ...) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
 public SearchResponse search(@Valid MyMapQuery query) {
```

and add the necessary bean-validation annotations to the fields of MyMapQuery.